# react preloading progress bar between routes

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-router, progress, virtual-dom

This isn't an intentionally broad question but i simply cannot find a good example of how to do this.

I am trying to figure out how i do a percentage progress bar between routes in a react project. Are there any methods on the document or window which give you the total amount of data to be downloaded? then somehow find the current download and divide that by the total times 100.

Any help in figuring this out would be appreciated. Im not looking for packages that do it, just a rough idea of how to do this.

Comment: What data?......

Comment: I wanted the loader progress bar for loading the react bundle

Comment: Are you using `dynamic import`? `import('./blah')`?

Comment: Yes on the app.js where the routes and heart of the app lives.